# Internship in Japan

Tags: indian-citizens, japan, japanese-visitors

I'm an Indian citizen and a final year student pursuing a bachelor degree. I plan to do a summer internship in Japan around May-July.

My official graduation date is June, but I get my physical degree later around August. The visa agent for my company said that neither the internship visa for students nor work visa will be applicable for me in this case, since I won't be a student in midst of the term.

However, I did not find any such rules written on VFS site. Is there really no visa that I can get?

Comment: Is there a way to transfer this question to Expatriates?